# How to compress video in android

Tags: android, video

How can I compress a video in android. After searching a lot I found a library called ffmpeg. But it will work only in NKD and it is a commercial version. I found another solution that is mp4Parcer. But this too not working. Is there any Native library for android to Compress Video. After searching a lot I found a class called MediaCodec in android. But I don't know how to compress video in it.

I hope anybody will answer my question

Thanks.

Comment: You wanna compress a video by coding? Why not change the format of video?

Comment: You can also find ffmpeg library .so files and include it in your project and use it without ndk. I have used it earlier.

Comment: use this-http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code to compress a video with ffmpeg android. I am using eclipse for development

Comment: Can anyone guide me to integrate it with my app

Comment: @touchQDeveloper Check out https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I am able to compress video using [this](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android) ffmpeg precompiled library

To compress a video we can use below command-

```
String[] command = {"-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-s", "160x120", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

For detailed explanation,check out [this](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/) tutorial which I have posted on my blog